# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main : application has stopped error

Tags: java, android, opencv

I get the error Fatal Exception main whenever I run application .
the app uses opencv 2.4.10 it has worked on one device and it fails on my device I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

I don't know which part is code is causing this error :

```
09-13 10:55:30.039 19555-19555/org.blatnik.eyemon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.blatnik.eyemon, PID: 19555
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.blatnik.eyemon.MainService@66d5693 with Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.blatnik.eyemon/.MainService }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1897)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:853)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:337)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:350)
    at **org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback.onPackageInstall(BaseLoaderCallback.java:110)
    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.InstallService(AsyncServiceHelper.java:117)
    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV(AsyncServiceHelper.java:33)
    at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.java:85)
    at org.blatnik.eyemon.MainService.onStartCommand(MainService.java:140)**
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4062)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:221) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1897) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

please any solution would be very thankful.

Comment: Are you trying to open a dialog from service?

Comment: It seems that you are communication directly from `Service`, Please add your code

Comment: the app should open front or back camera for face detection but when I press start to run the app it crashes.      this is the how it looks  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B03WnxRSaChVRE5BczJUN1hod2VUN1JiWjEyR1l2eEJnT0Jj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the main service code : http://paste.ofcode.org/ZBqRtsAe6gdNaTtcZN2MK8

Comment: AsyncServiceHelper  : http://paste.ofcode.org/tRkVTLPjdrHhSjidBDscPi

Comment: (BaseLoaderCallback.java   :  http://paste.ofcode.org/RRe4RWxnSwTtwKdVYSvhRw

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a task running  which is using the `context` here with `OpenCBLoader`

```
(!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback))
```

The problem related with `context` i.e the context is not valid anymore
.Try passing `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`

```
(!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, getApplicationContext(), mLoaderCallback))
```

Consider a case when AMK(android memory killer) kill your `service` due to memory shortage because service get to destroyed first before foreground activity and now your service is dead, plus the `this` context is not valid anymore hence Exception

Comment: Now when I press start the app not crashes but this message is displayed in android studio :                                                              OpenCVManager/Helper: Request new service installation
org.blatnik.eyemon I/MainService: OpenCV Load Failure

Comment: seems like you need to use the latest version of openCV 2.4.4 because it's a bug in 2.4.3. check [this link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6891/loading-opencv-on-android-fail-sometimes/)

Comment: what I should change if I use opencv 2.4.4 ?

Comment: download and use latest opencv dependancy